# Пропадает кнопка назад(DisplayHomeAsUpEnabled) после нажатия во втором фрагменте

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-toolbar, fragment-transaction

Есть `активити`, `фрагмент1`, `фрагмент2` и включена кнопка назад `(DisplayHomeAsUpEnabled)`.
В `фрагменте2` при нажатии кнопки назад переходит в `фрагмент1` но пропадает кнопка назад, в чем ошибка?

Структура такая: `Активити` > `фрагмент1` > `фрагмент2`.

Код `активити`:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener, View.OnClickListener {

    private static FragmentManager mManager;
    Button button1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Fragment fragment = null;


                    mManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
                    if (fragment == null) {
                        fragment = new sovety_Fragment();
                        mManager.beginTransaction()
                                .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
                                .addToBackStack(null)
                                .commit();
                    }

                }


            });

    }



    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                onBackPressed();
            {
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

            }  }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
  }
```

Код `фрагмента1`:

```
public class sovety_Fragment extends Fragment {
    Button button2;
    private static FragmentManager mManager;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sovety, null);

        button2 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        mManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();



        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment fragment = null;


                mManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
                if (fragment == null) {
                    fragment = new sovety_Fragment2();
                    mManager.beginTransaction()

                            .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
                            .addToBackStack(null)
                            .commit();
                }

            }


        });

        return v;
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

}
```

Код фрагмента2:

```
public class sovety_Fragment2 extends Fragment {



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sovety2, null);





        return v;
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Ну так вы её прячете в обработчике нажатия на кнопку назад, вот она и пропадает)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте управление отображением кнопки назад только в активити подписавшись на изменения бэкстека, это решит эту и многие другие проблемы. И удалите setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled из остальных методов и классов.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnBackStackChangedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // ...
        getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResumeFragments() {
        super.onResumeFragments();
        onBackStackChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackStackChanged() {
        int backStackEntryCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(backStackEntryCount > 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: удалил все setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled везде и заменил в активити на ваш код , стрелочка вообще пропала(((

Comment: @Андрей, пропало т.к. надо в коде `getActionBar()`  заменить на `getSupportActionBar()`

Comment: я заменил, все равно((((((

Comment: @Андрей, а если `getFragmentManager()` заменить на  `geSupporttFragmentManager()`

Comment: кнопка появилась но не работает((( при нажатии ничего не происходит

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: @Андрей, не вызывается обработчик нажатия?..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, при нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит

Comment: @Андрей, вы не ответили на мой вопрос. А вообще - задавайте отдельный вопрос лучше, чем тут в комментах.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, наверное да

Comment: Сори, забыл дописать Support при копипасте.

Comment: @xkor не работает... иконка появилась но при нажатии ничего не происходит

Comment: @Андрей ну так вы судя по другому вашему вопросу удалили обработчик этой кнопки заодно)