# При нажатии на кнопку назад(DisplayHomeAsUpEnabled) ничего непроисходит?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-toolbar, fragment-transaction

Есть активити, фрагмент1, фрагмент2 и включена кнопка назад (DisplayHomeAsUpEnabled). 
Иконка отображается но при нажатии ничего не происходит?

Код активити:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener, View.OnClickListener, FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener {
    private static FragmentManager mManager;
    Button button1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);




            button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Fragment fragment = null;


                    mManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
                    if (fragment == null) {
                        fragment = new sovety_Fragment();
                        mManager.beginTransaction()
                                .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
                                .addToBackStack(null)
                                .commit();
                    }

                }


            });

    }



    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
    @Override
    protected void onResumeFragments() {
        super.onResumeFragments();
        onBackStackChanged();
    }


    public void onBackStackChanged() {
        int backStackEntryCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(backStackEntryCount > 0);
    }


}
```

Код после изменений:

```
package com.whitestar.topcar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener, View.OnClickListener, FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener {
    private static FragmentManager mManager;
    Button button1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);


            button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Fragment fragment = null;


                    mManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
                    if (fragment == null) {
                        fragment = new sovety_Fragment();
                        mManager.beginTransaction()
                                .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
                                .addToBackStack(null)
                                .commit();
                    }

                }


            });

    }



    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                onBackPressed();

                if(id == android.R.id.home)
                {
                    int backStackEntryCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
                    if(backStackEntryCount > 0) {getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);}
                    else { getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);  }
                    onBackPressed();
                }  }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
    @Override
    protected void onResumeFragments() {
        super.onResumeFragments();
        onBackStackChanged();
    }


    public void onBackStackChanged() {
        int backStackEntryCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(backStackEntryCount > 0);
    }


}
```

Comment: Кнопка на разметке ничего не будет делать, пока ВЫ не напишите обработчик на клик по кнопке, в которлм и будет реализовано действие

Comment: @pavlofff, добавил обработчик появилась старая проблема <ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/481432>

Comment: Значит неправильно что то добавляете.

Comment: @pavlofff добавил но происходит дойной клик при нажатии

Comment: Я не телепат, к сожалению, определять из за чего у вас двойные клики. Создавайте вопрос с проблемой, раз сам не можете справится.

Comment: @pavlofff добавил код после изменений, посмотрите пожалуйста, у меня голова дырка полная, непонимаю в чем ошибка

Comment: Не нужно изменять вопросы таким образом, чтобы пришлось решать другую проблему (не первоначальную проблему в вопросе). Здесь вы спрашивали, почему ничего не происходит и получили ответ. По новой проблеме создайте новый вопрос.

Comment: @pavlofff спасибо большое))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы опять забыли обработать нажатие на стрелку:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    ...
    if(id == android.R.id.home)
    {
        int backStackEntryCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
        if(backStackEntryCount > 0) {getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);}
        else { getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);  }
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: добавил код, но после добавления кода появилась другая проблема http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/481432/Пропадает-кнопка-назадdisplayhomeasupenabled-после-нажатия-во-втором-фрагменте?rq=1

Comment: @Андрей, см. обновлённый ответ. А вообще вам надо разобраться в собственном коде и понять где что и когда вызывается. Мы не может всю программу за вас написать.

Comment: работает но при нажатии происходит двойной клик, тоесть есле например быть в фрагменте2 и нажать на кнопку назад переходит не в фрагмент1 а в активити... я пробую, учюсь разбираюсь  но возникают ошибки

Comment: Помогите пожалуйста, мне больше никто не поможет((((

Comment: добавил код после изменений, посмотрите пожалуйста, у меня голова дырка полная, непонимаю в чем ошибка

Comment: Юрий помогите в последний раз больше не буду просить

Comment: УМАЛЯЯЯЯЯЯЯЯЯЯЯЯЯЯЯЯЯЯЮЮЮЮЮЮЮЮЮЮЮЮЮЮЮ

Comment: См. Обновленный ответ

Comment: не помогло((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((

Comment: что делать ((((( как исправить??? (((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((

Comment: ПОМОГЛО УУУУУРРРРРРРРРРРРРРРАААААААААААААА

Comment: СПАСИБО БОЛЬШОЕ НИКОГДА НЕ ЗАБУДУ

Comment: у меня башка дырка вот что было : `if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                onBackPressed();

                if(id == android.R.id.home)
                {
                    int backStackEntryCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
                    if(backStackEntryCount > 0) {getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);}
                    else { getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);  }
                    onBackPressed();
                }  }
`